# queueing package not reading any functions?

Tags: r

I've loaded the queueing package into R.

But None of the funtions are working such as NewInput or QueueingModel.

```
x <- NewInput.MM1(lambda=25,mu=30)
y <- NewINput.MMC(lambda=25,mu=6,c=5)


a <- QueueingModel(x)
b <- QueueingModel(y)

summary(a); summary(b)
```

Maybe if I put `queueing::` in front of the function but it still didn't work.

```
a <- queueing::QueueingModel(x)
b <- queueing::QueueingMode(y)
```

[image: Package is loaded]

Is there another package I should load?

Comment: have you loaded that package with the library command as well before running the above code: ```library(queueing)```?

Answer (score 0):

You have said that the functions "aren't working", but don't give any details of the errors you are getting. The following is a reprex, meaning if you copy and paste the first three lines into your R console, you should get the exact same output. If not, please report back with the exact error you received:

```r
library(queueing)
x <- NewInput.MM1(lambda = 25, mu = 30)
QueueingModel(x)
#> $Inputs
#> $lambda
#> [1] 25
#> 
#> $mu
#> [1] 30
#> 
#> $n
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "i_MM1"
#> 
#> $RO
#> [1] 0.8333333
#> 
#> $Lq
#> [1] 4.166667
#> 
#> $VNq
#> [1] 28.47222
#> 
#> $Wq
#> [1] 0.1666667
#> 
#> $VTq
#> [1] 0.03888889
#> 
#> $Throughput
#> [1] 25
#> 
#> $L
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $VN
#> [1] 30
#> 
#> $W
#> [1] 0.2
#> 
#> $VT
#> [1] 0.04
#> 
#> $Wqq
#> [1] 0.2
#> 
#> $Lqq
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $Pn
#> [1] 0.1666667
#> 
#> $Qn
#> [1] 0.1666667
#> 
#> $FW
#> function (t) 
#> {
#>     1 - exp(-t/W)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000000000f397938>
#> <environment: 0x000000000f397270>
#> 
#> $FWq
#> function (t) 
#> {
#>     1 - (RO * exp(-t/W))
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000000000f397d98>
#> <environment: 0x000000000f397270>
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "o_MM1"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>